# Animating Ext.Panel in Sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have this view that I want to slide in:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.AddBidView', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config: {   
        xtype: 'panel',
        modal: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '50%', 
        bottom: '0%',
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            name: 'bio',        
            clearIcon: false,
            id: 'textarea',
            placeHolder: 'Ange ditt bud här...'
        },
        {
            xtype:'button',
            text: 'Lägg bud',
            docked:'bottom',
            maxWidth: '95%',
            minHeight: '45px',
            cls: 'saveBidBtn'
        }]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.down('#textarea').on('keyup', this.grow, this);
        this.textarea = this.element.down('textarea');
        this.textarea.dom.style['overflow'] = 'hidden';
    },

    grow: function() {
        this.textarea.setHeight(this.textarea.dom.scrollHeight); // scrollHeight is height of all the content
        this.getScrollable().getScroller().scrollToEnd();
    }
});
```

It is rendered by this controller:

```
Ext.define('GS.controller.ShowModal', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',    
    config : {   
        control : {
            'button[action="showBidModal"]' : {
                tap : 'showModal'
            },
        }
    },
    showModal : function() {
        var addBidPanel = Ext.create('GS.view.AddBidView');
        Ext.Viewport.add(addBidPanel);
    }
});
```

How can I animate this with a slide up/slide down or similar? Tried a bunch of stuff but nothing seems to work.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to hide the modal by default:

```
hidden: true
```

Then you can apply [**showAnimation**](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-showAnimation) and [**hideAnimation**](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-hideAnimation) to `show` and `hide` your modal with specified animation, for example:

```
showAnimation: {
    type: 'slideIn',
    duration: 1000,
    direction: 'down'
}, 

hideAnimation: {
    type: 'slideOut',
    duration: 1000,
    direction: 'up'
},
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#6tN6b